# Is it acceptable to include a link to the help center in an unrelated answer?

Tags: discussion, editing-help

Today I ran across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240312/937377) which links to this page in the help center at the end:

[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Presumably the answerer did this because the OP looks to be very new to the site. (They only have 16 reputation.)

My gut reaction is that this link should be removed immediately, as it has nothing to do with the question, and would be more appropriate as a comment, if anything.

Is this the correct call?

Comment: It doesn't looks like a good practise. It may encourage others to do the same. I removed the link

Comment: Looks like this is not the only time they have done this.  [I've found 20 other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22What+should+I+do+when+someone+answers+my+question%3F%22)  I'm going to start edited it out of.

Comment: @NathanOliver finished. you come from top and I came from bottom. we met at one and we've finished editing

Comment: Wow, great work, @NathanOliver and @SagarV!

Comment: As the answerer is someone with 24k rep I'm very surprised to see this

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is this the correct call?

Yes.

> would be more appropriate as a comment, if anything

I wouldn't even go that far.  I wouldn't *flag* it as a comment, but I certainly wouldn't go out of my way to tell them to post it as a comment, as it's still pretty noisy.

Comment: …And, if it is a comment and an answer has been accepted, then the comment is 'no longer needed' and can be flagged for removal.